# Ensuring Single Instance of SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications

How can I ensure only single instance of my SpringBoot Application should run.

I am starting my spring boot application with 
**java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

I need to ensure that if someone run this command second time on the same JVM,my application should not start.
One approach can be to create a lock file at the application startup and delete the lock file at application shutdown.But this will require a lot of boiler plate code.
Is there any better approach to do this Spring Boot?

Comment: Assuming it's a web app, it will oper a server socket on a port, and trying to start it again will fail because this socket is already open. So you don't need to do anything.

Comment: I am using an externalize application.propeties file.So if someone change port in the property file, the second instance will also be up.

Comment: Sure. But then if someone deletes the lock file, the result will be the same. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Normally we kept such lock file as hidden so users wont delete them.
Does SpringBoot offer something out of box for this or I have to manually handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To control the number of instances of an app (which could be running on different machines). I have used these techniques.

- Database table to track: e.g a MY_APP_STATUS table that could record IP, instance-name etc. App shuts down self if same ip, same instance name is already running.

I'm assuming your app already does some data-access, in which case it is a one line method in spring-data.